# JMock Expecting Custom Class

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I have the following expectation in a JUnit test class:

```
CustomEvent myCustomEvent = new CustomEvent(data1, data2);
m_context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(handler).somethingHappened(myCustomEvent); }});
```

In the class that is being tested, I am calling `handler.somethingHappened` with an instance of `CustomEvent` using the same arguments in the test class. However JMock claims an unexpected invocation when this occurs in the class being tested.

The JMock error shows a difference object reference to the one that was created in the class, so I'm assuming this is why I am having the unexpected reference.

My question is, how can I change my expectation so that I can test that the objects are actually equal? Equal being the contents of the object rather the memory reference.

Thanks

Comment: does `CustomEvent` have an appropriate implementation of `equals()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is `myCustomEvent` related to the one that appears in the code during the test? The default match is to call `equals()`, otherwise you should use a matcher to describe that relationship (and don't forget the `with` clause)

Comment: Thanks to you, and kem for the answer. Once I had implemented the `equals` method inside `myCustomEvent`, everything worked.